# How to clear aws batch job history in dashbord

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

In aws batch `Job queues` dashboard, it shows all job status failed and succeeded job count for 24 hours. Is it possible to reset counter to zero?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to clear jobs. Batch keeps finished jobs around for at least a day (and in my experience occasionally up to a few weeks), and there's no API or console mechanism to accelerate the process.